# getting undefined value of imported function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am filtering data based on texts typed in the searchbox. I am first filtering the data and then mapping it. My code is working is as expected but there is the repetition of a function so I put it into the `util` folder and then use it in the file. But the problem is that the value I am getting is `undefined` from that util function.

Previous code of Members.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import members from '../members.json'

function Member({searchTerm}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        members.filter((ele) =>
                ele.first_name
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase()) ||
                ele.last_name
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase()))
        .map(ele => {
          return (
            <div key={ele.id}>
              <h1>Name: {ele.first_name} {ele.last_name}</h1>
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Member
```

My new approach with Utils

utils/helper.js:

```
const searchMembers = (membersArr, searchTerm) => {
  return membersArr.filter(
    (ele) =>
      ele.first_name
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase()) ||
      ele.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())
  );
}

export { searchMembers }
```

Members.js

```
import React from 'react'
import members from '../members.json'
import {searchMembers} from '../utils/helper'

function Member({searchTerm}) {
  const {searchMember} = searchMembers(members, searchTerm)
  console.log('searchMember:', searchMember)      //undefined
  return (
    <div>
      {
        searchMember.map(ele => {
          return (
            <div key={ele.id}>
              <h1>Name: {ele.first_name} {ele.last_name}</h1>
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Member
```

For above approach I am getting error `searchMember.filter is not a function`.

Can you guys please help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `searchMembers` method returns the filtered results directly. While your code

```
const {searchMember} = searchMembers(members, searchTerm)
```

tries to extract a `searchMember` from the returned data (*through destructuring*).

use

```
const searchMember = searchMembers(members, searchTerm)
```